# Cloudwatch alarm for IAM Policies changes doesn't work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudtrail

I'm just trying to create fully functional alarm that will change state if there's any IAM Policies changes will be made.

1. Create an S3 Bucket for Cloudtrail logs.
2. Create trail in Cloudtrail.
3. Add Metric filter:

`{($.eventName=DeleteGroupPolicy)||($.eventName=DeleteRolePolicy)||($.eventName=DeleteUserPolicy)||($.eventName=PutGroupPolicy)||($.eventName=PutRolePolicy)||($.eventName=PutUserPolicy)||($.eventName=CreatePolicy)||($.eventName=DeletePolicy)||($.eventName=CreatePolicyVersion)||($.eventName=DeletePolicyVersion)||($.eventName=AttachRolePolicy)||($.eventName=DetachRolePolicy)||($.eventName=AttachUserPolicy)||($.eventName=DetachUserPolicy)||($.eventName=AttachGroupPolicy)||($.eventName=DetachGroupPolicy)}`

4. Create Alarm for this filter by using created Metric and Metricname.

If I attach or detach any policy for any IAM Role - nothing happening.

There's a policies for cloudwatch role:

```
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "cloudtrail:StartLogging",
                "cloudtrail:StopLogging",
                "cloudtrail:Get*",
                "cloudtrail:CreateTrail",
                "cloudtrail:UpdateTrail",
                "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
                "iam:CreateRole",
                "iam:PutRolePolicy",
                "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "iam:GetRolePolicy",
                "iam:GetUser",
                "iam:GetPolicy",
                "iam:GetPolicyVersion",
                "iam:GetRole"
                "autoscaling:Describe*",
                "cloudwatch:*",
                "logs:*",
                "sns:*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

Anyone can advise why there's no changes in alarm state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out:
It works correctly only in the us-east-1 region.
I saw a hint in some instructions, which said something completely different, and decided to try setting up IAM Changes Alarm in another region.

@shimo, thanks for reassuring me that my settings are completely correct.

Comment: Good to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

Your Metric filter works fine, and the role is ok (it seems too much, though).

Try to check your filter can detect from your own trail logs by testing on the console.

[image]

Check the state of the alarm is OK.

[image]

Check the Metrics are found properly.

[image]

Note: I think when setting CW alarms, we need to wait a while (several minutes or so). Immediate actions do not work.

Comment: I'm even don't have any records about IAM changes in the "test pattern" as well as in CloudTrail events. There is nothing about IAM in any log_data..
Of course, I wait a bit after setting...

Comment: ? 
any updates? didn't get then what am I doing wrong that is don't work..